# retrieve data from pandas.core.series.series and save them into matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a variable generated while running a program, which has the series type, and contents shown as follows. It can be seen that `test_prior` is a series, where each series element is a also a series. How to retrieve these element series and save them into a numpy array. Or, is that possible to save this whose series, i.e., `test_prior`, into a matrix?

```
type(test_prior)
pandas.core.series.Series

test_prior
0      [0.0032125000000000005, 0.003213987572590001, ...
1      [0.0037124999999999997, 0.00371353755063, 0.00...
2      [0.0003125, 0.0003170377214300023, 0.000321575...
3      [0.0048625, 0.004865587650670002, 0.0048686753...
4      [0.0020875, 0.0020882125347700003, 0.002088925...
                             ...                        
195    [0.0010625, 0.0010631875335500003, 0.001063875...
196    [0.0009875, 0.0009895876018700012, 0.000991675...
197    [0.0024375, 0.0024401126274900013, 0.002442725...
198    [0.0022375, 0.0022403376384700015, 0.002243175...
199    [0.0005125, 0.000514487596990001, 0.0005164751...
Length: 200, dtype: object
```

Comment: The elements are probably lists, maybe numpy arrays.  Have you looked at `test_prior.values`?

Comment: Agreed, they look like lists/arrays, not series. Check `type(test_prior[0])`

Comment: type(test_prior) is numpy.ndarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can convert the `Series` to a `DataFrame` and then use `explode`:

```
test_prior.to_frame().apply(lambda c: c.explode(), axis=1)
```

Note that this will only work if the array in each row has the same length. But if this was not the case, then arranging your data into two dimensions wouldn't seem to make sense.

Comment: can also apply `pd.Series.explode` directly without the lambda: `test_prior.to_frame().apply(pd.Series.explode, axis=1)`